# C# Intercept Browse Button

Tags: c#, html, webforms

Have a unique customer request which Im unsure how to tackle.

The customer has a webpage form with a browse button to select a file.  When the browse button is clicked, instead of showing the local files, they want to pop-up a window with a textbox to enter a code.  This code is then used to select a file from a local folder containing 1000 files each with their own code.  They want to prevent the user from viewing the other files in that folder.

I did write a custom Windows form to mimic the webpage form but they already have the webpage online and would like to reuse it.

Any ideas how to intercept the browse button?  I can use a C# Application with the web browser component, but can that intercept the browse button?

Comment: You have a nail. You are asking, "How do I screw this nail?" The answer is, don't use a nail, use a screw.

Comment: Also - How exactly would this scheme stop people from just typing random codes until they hit a file they should not have access too?

Comment: The files are on the user's computer? You do realize that the user can view these files anyway as long as they are on his computer?

Comment: @asawyer: Yes, but which size wrench do you pound the screw in with?

Comment: the computer is at an exhibition, not in someones home. the browser will be on full screen with people watching what they are doing, so they couldn't just go "exploring". To your question of "How exactly would this scheme stop people from just typing random codes until they hit a file they should not have access too".. could be asked about any password protected data

Answer (score 1):

The only option that I can see working is using a C# Application with the web browser component. You can then use [`WebBrowser.ObjectForScripting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting.aspx) to provide a method that can be called to trigger your custom picker window through Javscript, e.g:

```
window.external.ShowPickerWindow();
```

You then have two options:

1. Interrogate the DOM of the page once it's loaded and replace the button with one that triggers your picker window.
2. Have the customer change their page so it checks for the existance of a `window.external.ShowPickerWindow` method and basically does option (1) for you.

You can then have a method, perhaps called `window.external.GetPickedCode()` to pull the code out in the page.

Answer (score 1):

Rob kinder steered me along the correct thinking track by saying "replace the button" which has lead me to a solution which works beautifully!

In short, I hide the browse button, insert a new button next to it that when clicked, opens a new window with a textbox. This textbox then sets a string value in the parent form which is used onSubmit to attach the file.

```
    private void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlElement btnBrowse = wb.Document.GetElementById("fiPhoto");
        if (btnBrowse != null)
        {
            HtmlElement newbtn = wb.Document.CreateElement("input");
            newbtn.SetAttribute("id", "btnLoad");
            newbtn.SetAttribute("type", "button");
            newbtn.SetAttribute("value", "Load");
            newbtn.Click += new HtmlElementEventHandler(newbtn_Click);
            btnBrowse.Parent.AppendChild(newbtn);

            btnBrowse.Style = "display:none";
        }

        HtmlElementCollection forms = wb.Document.Forms;
        if (forms.Count > 0)
        {
            HtmlElement form = wb.Document.Forms[0];
            form.AttachEventHandler("onsubmit", delegate(object o, EventArgs arg)
                {
                    FormToMultipartPostData postData = new FormToMultipartPostData(wb, form);
                    postData.AddFile("photo", photo);
                    postData.Submit();
                });
        }
    }

    private void newbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm = new Form2(this);
        frm.ShowDialog();
    }
```

`FormToMultipartPostData` is too big to post in here but it basically manually constructs the Content-Disposition to be posted

Answer (score 0):

Don't show the actual file browser, imitate one which is showing only that one file in in.

Or since you know the file path when correct code is entered copy the file to temp folder you created and open file browser to browse that folder and it will be contain only that file.

Comment: how would you not show the actual file browser?  Bear in mind that this is an actual web page loaded from a server, not a webpage loaded from the local computer.